# Ajax converte url

Tags: jquery, ajax

Pessoal tenho uma rotina que envia uma pesquisa via AJAX para o meu PHP, so que quando eu tenho por exemplo a seguinte query: ?valor<=1000 ai ele converte para ?valor%253C=1000. A Request URL fica assim:

```
http://localhost/api/produtos?search=6&valor%253C=1000&per_page=10&page=1
```

Tem algo que eu possa fazer para o AJAX não converter estes caracteres?

Obrigado

Comment: não tem como, você terá de fazer o `html decode` no `php`

Comment: Em vez de usar `GET` use `POST`, ai nem aparece na url

Comment: Usar simbolos não seria a melhor forma de usar o querystring .... utilize nomes praticos para suas variaveis.

Comment: Valeu @TobyMosque deu certinho usando o urldecode. Obrigadão.